# Additional characters when unwrapping optional in Swift

Tags: string, swift, int, option-type

I'm extremely new to Swift, and I'm trying to build a simple calculator to test the waters.
I have a UILabel with name 'display', and I want to store its value as an int in a variable called 'numA'. However, when I did that, the variable numA gets the value nil.

I discovered why this happened, because when I simply print the display text in the console:

```
println("\(display.text!)")
```

I get this: " 6" instead of "6". Notice the additional space appended at the beginning. This is why I cannot do this:

```
var numA = display.text!.toInt()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you initializing your `display` to `" "` one space instead of `""` empty string?

Comment: How stupid can I be -_-
I didn't initialize it to " ", but it does become " " during a part of my code. Thanks for pointing it out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading space might be there because you are initializing your `display` to `" "` (a single space) instead of to `""` (empty string).  Even if you have spaces in your `display.text`, you can trim them out before calling `toInt()`.

Note that since `toInt()` returns an optional, you should use *optional binding* to unwrap it to prevent app crashes.  I recommend:

```
if let numA = display.text?.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()).toInt() {
    // use numA
}
```

Note the use of `?` after `text` instead of `!`.  This will keep your app from crashing if `display.text` is `nil`.  This is an example of an *optional chain*; if `display.text` is `nil`, the entire chain will be `nil`.

This can be further simplified by leaving out `NSCharacterSet` which Swift can infer from the call:

```
if let numA = display.text?.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(.whitespaceCharacterSet()).toInt() {
    // use numA
}
```

Comment: The display label was indeed " " by mistake.
Thanks for the workaround though, will definitely be useful sometime in the future too!